# Управление: 62 детскИХ жизни или 62 детскИЕ жизни?

Tags: числительные, управление

> Такие акции благотворители проводят с 2009 года, и с тех пор удалось собрать почти тринадцать миллионов рублей, которые **спасли 62 детских жизни**.

http://www.5-tv.ru/news/96817/

Есть ли в выделенном жирным фрагменте ошибка или это особенность склонения при числительном?

Answer (score 4):

Для существительных женского рода допускаются **оба вариант**а, но выбор зависит **не от семантики, а от грамматики**. В этом случае основной задачей является обеспечение **наилучшей сочетаемости стоящих рядом слов.**

Например, если с точностью до ударения совпадают формы: нет книги (Р. п. ед. ч.) и интересные книги (И. п. мн. ч.), то общелитературной нормой является сочетание: две интересные книги.

В современной речи оба варианта всё чаще рассматриваются **как параллельные нормы**, причем   при обозначение лиц даже чаще используется Р. п.: две российских спортсменки.

В то же время в каждом случае желательно у**читывать особенности варианта**.

**Решение**

Такие акции благотворители проводят с 2009 года, и с тех пор удалось собрать почти тринадцать миллионов рублей, которые спасли **62 детские жизни.**

Этот вариант мне кажется **более благозвучным, и вот по какой причине.** В этом случае первое числительное "шестьдесят" задает Р. п. мн. ч. (60 детских жизней),  и тогда числительное "две" выпадает из общего ряда и поэтому нуждается в грамматической поддержке (**две детские** жизни).

Answer (score 2):

Я не вижу ошибки. Насчет особенности - не знаю. По сравнению с чем особенность? Вроде бы тоже стандартно. И как бы вы написали иначе?

Тут другое. Прилагательные в подобных сочетаниях испытывают колебания в форме. Если в двух словах, при существительных мужского и среднего рода обычно (если не всегда) используется форма родительного падежа: "два красивых рисунка, платья". В женском роде иногда используется форма именительного: "две красивые сумки". Но форма "две красивых сумки" совсем не противоречит правилам, причем тем охотнее используется, чем больше (математически) число с которым используется. "Шестидесяти двух" - вполне достаточно для выбора такой формы.

Comment: (спасли что?) жизни (какие?) детские; у меня вопрос к согласованию прилагательного в родительном падеже с существительным в винительном

Comment: *(спасли что?) жизни* - не, так не пойдет. Сочетание числительного с существительным можно рассматривать только как единое целое в плане члена предложения, иначе вы не сможете включить в структуру само числительное. *Спасли что? - две жизни.* И сразу выбор вопроса *"каких?"* или *"какие?"* - уже становится неоднозначным.

Answer (score 2):

Второй вариант не может быть грамматической ошибкой (прилагательное согласовано и с существительным, и с числительным). Вопрос в том, допустим ли первый вариант, и если допустим, то как он соотносится со вторым по употреблению. Упростим до предметов и сопоставим:

> Сколько купили тарелок и каких? 62 синих (и 36 красных).
>
> Что  скажешь про них? Эти 62 синие тарелки индивидуально расписал
>   известный умелец.

По всей видимости, оба варианта грамматически возможны, но стилистически различаются акцентом на отвлечённое *количество* (первый вариант), либо на то, что каждый элемент группы названных сущностей чем-то близок собеседникам или индивидуально интересен (второй вариант). Как уже отмечено в другом ответе, количество предметов тоже может влиять на выбор: чем оно больше, тем меньше внимания к индивидуальным предметам и естественнее акцент на количество (-их).

В случае с "жизнями детей" второй вариант (-ие) "теплее": как бы подразумевается, что речь напр. о детях конкретного города, о которых перед этим рассказывали, и это не только статистика.